# Trackpad initially unresponsive

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.10, budgie

I am very new to Linux. Using Ubuntu Budgie currently and have Elementary as well in a dual boot (Elementary seems fine).

The last two times I booted into Ubuntu, touchpad works as expected at the login screen. Then once the desktop initializes the mouse is only partially responsive, moves on its own, becomes unresponsive and then seems to work perfectly fine after a bit.

I have no clue how to troubleshoot this because I have no experience and I am still learning the command line as well. I've been with Linux about a week and jumped distributions until Budgie. I apologize in advance for any noobishness!

(I did Google around but couldn't find anything that seemed to be the same issue)

Possibly helpful things:

```
 xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]

steven@steven-Satellite-L875D
OS: Ubuntu 17.10 artful
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.13.0-16-generic
Uptime: 58m
Packages: 1658
Shell: bash 4.4.12
Resolution: 1600x900
DE: Budgie
WM: BudgieWM
WM Theme: Arc-Darker
GTK Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: Pocillo
Font: Ubuntu 11
CPU: AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon HD Graphics @ 2x 2.7GHz [39.2°C]
GPU: AMD/ATI Trinity [Radeon HD 7520G]
RAM: 1098MiB / 5425MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10. Reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all` worked for me.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```